# MySQL can you use LIMIT to return n rows, but then also return any other row whose value matches the nth row?

Tags: mysql, limit

I am trying to limit my number of rows returned to the top 5 rows after they've been ordered, but I need to also return all other rows that share the same value as the 5th top value.

i.e.

```
Number of Traffic Tickets
         8                   
         7
         7 
         6
         4
         4
         4
         3
         2
```

should return 8, 7, 7, 6, 4, 4, 4 because 4 is the 5th value, and the other are 4's are 'tied'.

Is it possible to limit a row like this in MySQL?

```
SELECT NumTickets FROM drivers ORDER BY NumTickets DESC LIMIT 5 ???;
```

Is there something you can put in the question marks to achieve something like this in MySQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple ways to do this using a subquery.  This uses `IN`:

```
Select NumTickets
From drivers
Where NumTickets In (
    Select NumTickets 
    From drivers
    Order By NumTickets Desc
    Limit 5)
```

You could also use a `JOIN`:

```
Select d.NumTickets
From drivers d 
   join (
    Select NumTickets 
    From drivers
    Order By NumTickets Desc
    Limit 5) d2 on d.numTickets = d2.NumTickets
```

Comment: That will return more than 5?